# Mean over multiple axis in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization, mean

I Want to write the code below as Pythonic way, applying mean over two axis. What the best way to do this?

```
import numpy as np

m = np.random.rand(30, 10, 10)  
m_mean = np.zeros((30, 1))    
for j in range(30):
    m_mean[j, 0] = m[j, :, :].mean()
```

Comment: Why is `m_mean` a 2D array?

Comment: why create a second numpy array with only one row? why not just have a simple list?

Comment: NumPythonic way would be `m.mean(axis=(1,2))`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you have a sufficiently recent NumPy, you can do

```
m_mean = m.mean(axis=(1, 2))
```

I believe this was introduced in 1.7, though I'm not sure. The documentation was only updated to reflect this in 1.10, but it worked earlier than that.

If your NumPy is too old, you can take the mean a bit more manually:

```
m_mean = m.sum(axis=2).sum(axis=1) / np.prod(m.shape[1:3])
```

These will both produce 1-dimensional results. If you really want that extra length-1 axis, you can do something like `m_mean = m_mean[:, np.newaxis]` to put the extra axis there.

Comment: With older numpy, you can also just do `m.mean(axis=2).mean(axis=1)`

Comment: @Rob: Ah, you're right. Since all the means in the `m.mean(axis=2)` step are over the same number of elements, `m.mean(axis=2).mean(axis=1)` correctly gives each element equal weight.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [`numpy.mean()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) ufunc and pass the output array as an argument to `out=` as in:

```
np.mean(m, axis=(1, 2), out=m_mean)
```