# How to get the mean of a 3D array over 2D?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array with the following shape (7352, 128, 6)

How can I get the "mean" of the 1st and 2nd dimensions with NumPy in Python?

The resulting shape of the "means" I want to obtain is (1, 6).

Comment: `np.mean` has an `axis` parameter, which is exactly for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
np.mean(x, axis=(0, 1))
```

You resulting shape would be (6,) though.

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution I was looking for and yeah, sorry you're right about the shape!

Answer (score 1):

[`numpy.mean()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) with axis argument is proper solution.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(7352, 128, 6)
x_mean = np.mean(x, axis=(0, 1))

print(x_mean.shape)  # -> (6,)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the axis parameter of the [mean](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html?highlight=mean#numpy.mean) function:

```
img = np.random.rand(7352,128,6)
y_mean = img.mean(axis=0) # mean over y (row)
x_mean = img.mean(axis=1) # mean over x (column)
z_mean = img.mean(axis=(0,1)) # the mean you want (shape is (6,))
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33552287/7666241) may also help.